# Find/reduce scss errors in media query mixin

Tags: css, sass, bourbon, neat

We've been working with Neat framework for 6 months and love it.
However suddenly we have a critical problem with one of their excellent mixins which we are entirely dependant on for media queries. 
Here's a link to  the file.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/grid/_media.scss

Heres the docs for the mixin.
http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#media

We've called it in our sass files almost 300 times so its pretty essential, although we mostly only use the first parameters e.g.  media( max-width $small-screen) 
Although we have also used it in some of the Refills navigation modules which use it in a more advanced way
http://refills.bourbon.io/

Don't know what the error is because gulp-sass and browser-sync crash without sending error messages to the console like it normally does with the way we have it set up.They only crash when  this mixin is loaded. Don't know what causes the error

If I start removing  the mixin we get error reporting back and gulp-sass doesn't crash any more. ALthough we get errors from all the files that call the mixin.

I've also tried the following
Completely deleting the node_modules directory and doing a fresh npm install

1. Doing a npm uninstall of gulp and gulp-sass, then a fresh npm install
2. Doing a global install of node-sass, and doing a global uninstall of node-sass.
3. Doing a npm rebuild node-sass from within the node_modules/gulp-sass directory

Does anyone have any suggestions/ ideas / solutions ?

Comment: Can't you just try to compile this with, say, the SASS/Compass CLI and see if it throws out errors? You don't have to do everything, but just one example of where it goes wrong, see what errors it throws and try to fix those. You can always use SASS' `@debug` to print your own stuff to the console while compiling, so maybe that helps?

Comment: no errors because of crashing gulp-sass. I didn't know about @debug though. Im trying to use it now - thanks for the tip.

Comment: That's what I meant though, maybe if you do this file and one single implementation and run it through SASS or Compass itself instead of using gulp, it might help you hone into any potential issues? Maybe the problem is with gulp and it will compile just fine if you'd use the original SASS or Compass compilers - that would allow you to find out what part is causing the issue? Maybe its gulp?

Comment: the ruby  compiler worked better. Maybe it is gulp

Comment: Ok now I have an error message hooraye! error neat/grid/_media.scss (Line 87: Illegal nesting: Only properties maybe nested beneath properties)

Comment: Woooo! At least you know the issue now :) Good Luck!